# Why Windows Live Messenger on Win 7 doesn't pop up the window with the new message, but "let me choose"?

Tags: windows-7, instant-messaging, aero, windows-live-messenger

On Windows 7, when clicking on the small icon on the task bar, it is nice to pop up a few small windows and let me choose which one to use.

But, with Windows Live Messenger, when I have several chat windows open, and a friend send me a new message, so I click on the small icon, and it shows which one has the new message with an orange background, and still "let me choose" which window to open up.

In this situation, I think it is one that it can directly pop up the one with the new message, instead of letting the user scan which one has the new message, move the mouse to pinpoint that one, and click on it.

Or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following to make Live Messenger work like in XP or Vista for Win 7;

1-Open C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Messenger

2-Right Click "msnmsgr.exe"

3-Properties > Select Compatibility Mode

4-Activate compatibility box to select an OS

5-Select Windows Vista or Windows XP SP3

Comment: This works well. I would recommend setting the compatibility to Windows Vistra SP2 to remain as close as you can to the current OS, while retaining the older behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Windows Messenger feature you're really talking about here. You'll find the same behaviour in Windows 7 for all applications that are highlighted on the task bar.

I don't think you're asking something that's possible, because I think the behaviour is by design.

Comment: can't Messenger be smart to override this behavior? they are all MS apps... some app must be able to override the "let me choose" behavior or Win7 may be able incorporate that into their design, because in reality, not all apps want to exhibit the "let me choose" behavior.

Comment: I reckon you'll be better of filing a feature request with the Windows team, as opposed to asking here.

Comment: isn't this a forum for exploring possibilities, methods, and solutions too?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 stopped letting MSN work the way it wanted and made it work the same as every other application - which was a mistake IMHO.

I prefer MSN to hide itself away in the notification area and pop up message notifications. Conversations should appear in the task bar.

I can't think why they did this, but... there's no way to put it back the way it should be that I can find. What I'd suggest is to move to an alternative, like Pidgin, Digsby, Miranda or Trillian, or try a new messaging client like Skype or Google Talk.

Comment: My trick makes all that you wanna do...